# Finding what checkin broke a unit test

Tags: git, azure-devops

Some checkin over the last 3 days broke one of our unit tests (and why is not at all clear).

I'm assuming the best way to find which check in is to pull the code in the branch as of 3 days ago, verify the test passes, then keep pulling for a checkin halfway between works & fails to find the checkin that caused the problem.

Which leads to the questions:

1. How do I get a list of all IDs (?) of code checked in to the branch over the last 3 days.
2. How do I then pull that copy of the code (for that specific ID)?

We use Git via VSO (now Azure DevOps) if that matters.

thanks - dave

Comment: Please have a look at [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Comment: As for getting a list of all IDs checked in over the last 3 days, do a simple `git log`, pick a commit old enough and start the bisect operation from there.

Comment: A different question would be why your build system isn't already telling you at least which set of commits that broke the build? Did you make 3 days worth of commits before pushing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*UPDATE* to provide a bit more information about how to use `bisect`

---

What you are describing is exactly what `git bisect` does.  Then all you need is to identify one working commit (before the bug was introduced) and one broken commit (presumably the current one).

Now, the whole point of `bisect` is to find when things were last good (or first bad) because you don't know.  So when you identify "one working commit", having it be more recent is *slightly* quicker, but not enough as to matter. (Especially because any time you spend trying to be more precise in setting the starting piont, is time that bisect could be spending more efficiently finding exactly the commit where the bug was introduced.)

So if you know that a week ago, you locally had a good (pre-bug) copy checked out on master, you can give

```
master@{1 week ago}
```

This relies on the local reflog, so only works from a repo that had a good copy checked out at that time.  If that's not practical, you can use

```
git rev-list --until='1 week ago' -n1 master
```

to get the last commit created (according to the commit metadata) at least 1 week ago.  So something like

```
git bisect start $(git rev-list --until='1 week ago' -n1 master) master
```

For either of the above notations, you can use `3 days` instead of `1 week` and it would be *slightly* more efficient - i.e. you might expect 1 or 2 fewer searches before the bug is pinpointed.

So there's not a lot of value in trying to pre-test whether a commit has the bug if you're not sure; you can just use an older commit instead.  But if for whatever reason you *really* want to, you can use the same notations to check out a commit from a given time, and then test it however you like.

---

A bit of an aside, but do beware - it is quite popular these days to make "cleaner" histories by rebasing every branch before integrating it into the mainline.  And while these "cleaner" histories are indeed more linear and simple, they are also in fact *more likely to be dirty* in the sense that they contain commits that have never been tested.  If one of those commits happens to fail unit tests for reasons other than your bug - such as a merge inconsistency that got washed out in a later commit, then using `bisect` is suddenly not as easy, since merely the green/red status of your unit test suite will not tell you whether your bug is present.

*But* that would be a problem for the bug-searching strategy you describe in general (not just for `bisect`).  So if tracking the bug through history is viable at all, then `bisect` is the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure when it was last good - is there a way to check out a version from 3 days ago - and I can then run the test on that (the test is very fast)? And if so, how do I do that? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen - Updating to clarify